# need ‘typename’ before ‘..’ because ‘..’ is a dependent scope

Tags: c++

having trouble when trying to compile a template class.

In the .h file

```
template <typename dataType>
class Node {    
 private:
    dataType nodeData;
    Node<dataType>* nextLink;
    Node<dataType>* previousLink;
 public:    
    Node(const dataType& nodeData);

   // methods
```

In the .template file

```
template <typename dataType>
Node<dataType>::dataType Node<dataType>::getData() const {
    return nodeData;
};
```

The error I get when trying to compile is:

```
 need ‘typename’ before ‘Node<dataType>::dataType’ because ‘Node<dataType>’ is a dependent scope

 Node<dataType>::dataType Node<dataType>::getData() const {
```

So then I add typename and it then gives me this error:

```
error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘dataType’
       typename dataType getData() const;
                ^
error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
error: declaration of ‘int Node<dataType>::dataType’
error: shadows template parm ‘class dataType’
       template <typename dataType> 
                 ^
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: It looks like you put `typename` before `dataType` and not before `Node<dataType>::dataType` as the compiler indicates.  Is this the case?  Can you show the source after the code change?

Comment: The message says to put `typename` before `‘Node<dataType>::dataType`.  Not before `dataType`

Comment: @BrianCain don't think it is a duplicate of that

Comment: It looks like you have put `typename` in the declaration in the class, instead of the implementation. Voting to close as **lacking reproducible example**.

Comment: That said, the access control with getter member functions is not buying you anything down at this level, for a `Node`. No advantage, but much verbosity and complexity. I'd just remove it, use a simple `struct`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no member called `dataType`, I assume the return type should be just the template `dataType`:

```
template <typename dataType>
dataType Node<dataType>::getData() const {
    return nodeData;
}
```

The compiler message is misleading in this case as it doesn't find proper definition, it assumes the `dataType` refers to the template argument.

Answer (score 2):

```
template <typename DataType>
class Node {
public:
    using dataType = DataType;
private:
    dataType nodeData;
    Node<dataType>* nextLink;
    Node<dataType>* previousLink;
public:    
    Node(const dataType& nodeData);
    dataType getData() const;
};
template <typename DataType>
typename Node<DataType>::dataType Node<DataType>::getData() const {
    return nodeData;
};
```

specfy `typename` like this.

http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Agu2s6vw6OLfbbRh

Answer (score 0):

The presented example code is **incomplete**, so one would have to guess at the concrete problem.

However, here's how to do that class in a practical way, without problems like the one you're encountering:

```
template< class Item >
struct Node
{
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
    Item item;
};
```

Showing that it's sometimes possible to solve a problem without knowing the exact details.